# Is there a rotational-to-linear machine that doesn't allow the slider to impart torque while _between_ extremes?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motion

Consider a machine for converting rotational motion to rectilinear translation, such as a crank slider or scotch yoke.

When the slider is at either of its two translational extremes (where the crank center, crank joint, and slider joint are all in a line), the machine is stable in the sense that applying a force on the slider (in the direction of the slider) does not result in any torque on the crank.

My **question** is: Is there a machine that converts rotational motion to rectilinear motion where the machine is stable (in this sense) when the slider is *between* its translational extremes?

Comment: "*stable (in this sense) when the slider is between its translational extremes*" The more straightforward way to word this is to simply describe it as something a rotary to linear motion converter that cannot be back driven. A leadscrew will do that.

Comment: What machines have you considered so far so we don”t duplicate your efforts made already.